# How to Compile and Install PHP7 on raspberry pi?

Tags: php

When i installed PHP on Raspberry PI, PHP version is 5.5.*
But, I want to install php7 and when i try to compile it from Source
Some Error occurs related to `sapi`
Did someone successfully installed php7 on their raspberry pi.

`/usr/bin/ld: ext/standard/.libs/image.o: undefined reference to symbol 'uncompress'
//lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so.1: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:268: recipe for target 'sapi/cli/php' failed
make: *** [sapi/cli/php] Error 1
p`

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please be more specific about *some errors occured* to help people give meaningful answers. You can always add your question to include those details.

Answer (score 3):

Title suggests compilation, but your last question just concerns a successful installation. If you're using Raspbian - which is generally a Debian distribution you can just search for existing .deb files for PHP7. I use `Jessie' version on my rpis, which has available compiled packages:
https://www.dotdeb.org/2015/12/04/php-7-0-0-is-available-for-jessie/
for x86/amd64 - it should be easier to recompile source DEBs than to compile all by yourself.

There are also packages for ARM:
https://packages.debian.org/search?arch=arm&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=php7.0

For getting help on compilation you need to pass additional info. I'd start with getting apt-get build-dep for available 5.6 version and add dependencies from there.

Comment: I am using Raspbian/wheezy, and the armhf packages from debian are not working, it says `segmentation fault`

Answer (score 1):

The DSO error is misleading because it makes you think you need to edit / update the Makefile, but in reality, it's actually complaining that it cannot find certain includes or libraries. (In your case, a library).

In my case, I had this issue because I needed to specify the `--with-libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` and then `--with-libxml-dir=/usr` and `--with-openssl-dir=/usr` (the `=/usr` bit was important, previously, I had `=/usr/include`).

Once this was corrected, it compiled just fine.

Also, you have to make sure that you have all the dependencies installed.

I have written an installation script that is tested and works on Raspbian 9.9 (Debian 9.9 Stretch), which *should* work, but otherwise you can use as a reference:

https://github.com/mjmunger/raspberry-pi-php-7.2